# Mutating func with external detection which variable to mutate

Tags: swift, mutating-function

I have a struct with 2 variables. This struct has mutating function, but in this function I need to check, which variable to mutate. For this I use separate class' static function with complex logic. This class works with different structs, so for DRY purpose I can't represent this logic in all these structs.

The problem is, that I don't know how to receive the same struct's variable from this separate class, so no struct's variables are mutate. I think, that I miss some Swift knowledge, because I'm sure, that it is possible, without duplicating logic.

Code to represent it in Playground:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var a = "a"
    var b = "b"

    mutating func mutateString(to newString: String) {
        var varToMutate = VariableDetector.whichVarToMutate(a, b)
        varToMutate = newString

        // prints to represent question
        print("varToMutate: \(varToMutate)")
        print("a: \(a)")
        print("b: \(b)")
    }
}

class VariableDetector {
    static func whichVarToMutate(_ first: String, _ second: String) -> String {
        var firstOrSecondString = ""

        // simple logic to represent question, in real case it is far more complex
        if first == "a" {
            firstOrSecondString = first
        } else {
            firstOrSecondString = second
        }

        return firstOrSecondString
    }
}

var someStruct = SomeStruct()
someStruct.mutateString(to: "c")
```

This code produces:

```
varToMutate: c
a: a
b: b
```

Yes, it can be solved with:

```
if varToMutate == a {
    a = newString
} else if varToMutate == b {
    b = newString
}
```

But I want to solve it in more elegant way :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: On a side note, it's not very customary to use classes for defining only static methods. Either you can just make those methods into functions with a narrow access specifier (e.g. `fileprivate` or `internal`, so as to limit global namespace population), or you can use a caseless `enum` (which protects against accidental instantiation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 4, this could be done by returning a `KeyPath` from `whichVarToMutate`. The `KeyPath` could then be used to access into the instance in question, and mutate the property it represents.

In Swift 3, there are 2 approaches I can think of:

1. Pass a mutator closure to the decider method, which passes out the appropriate var to mutate as an `inout` param, and then has the closure body mutate it.
2. Define a protocol that contains these variables (that you said are shared between multiple types), make those types conform to it, and provide an extension on the protocol that defines a method, which will apply to all of them. This is the approach I would use, even in Swift 4:

   ```
   struct SomeStruct {
       var a = "a"
       var b = "b"
   }

   protocol Mutable { // TODO: Rename me appropriately
       var a: String { get set }
       var b: String { get set }
   }

   extension SomeStruct: Mutable {}

   extension Mutable {
       mutating func changeAppropriateVar(to newValue: String) -> Void {
           // simple logic to represent question, in real case it is far more complex
           let someCondition = true

           if someCondition {
               print("Setting `a` to \(newValue)")
               a = newValue
           }
           else {
               print("Setting `b` to \(newValue)")
               b = newValue
           }
       }
   }

   var s = SomeStruct()
   s.changeAppropriateVar(to: "foo")
   ```

Comment: Alexander, it's brilliant :) Thanks for the answer and comment!

Comment: @PeterTretyakov Any time you end up extracting common logic like this, think "Can I do this with a protocol and an extension that provides a default implementation?". Most times it's a yes.

Comment: Crusty way :) In fact I thought, that it can be solved with protocol, but protocol concept is still not very clear to me. P.S. If someone find this question, look at this video from WWDC2015 about protocol-oriented programming https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/

Comment: @PeterTretyakov Hah. Good ol' Crusty.

Comment: @PeterTretyakov Do you have a Java background?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148521/discussion-between-alexander-and-peter-tretyakov).

Answer (score 1):

Unless `a` and `b` are instances of a class, your `varToMutate` will only be a copy, because everything besides a Class is a value-type in Swift. Maybe try `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`?